# Can you kill a parent process while leaving its child process to complete normally?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process

I'm running a shell script we'll call `parent` that has a loop. Each iteration in the loop executes something else we'll call `child`, and when that completes (synchronous/blocking), my script goes to the next iteration.

Is there a way in linux to detach `child` from the `parent` process, and then kill `parent` while leaving the current `child` to complete normally?

(I think next time I'll include a check inside my loop for the existence of a stop file, and if the file is present, I'll break out of the loop instead of launching the next `child`. But seeing as the `parent` that's currently running doesn't have that logic, is there still a way for me to accomplish what I want at the command line?)

Comment: in the shell use `command <paramenters> &` to detach and do not wait for the child to finish

Comment: Compare [*What happens to background jobs after exiting the shell?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/318428/108618) and [*Control which process gets cancelled by Ctrl+C*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163561/108618). Your `child` probably gets SIGHUP from `parent` or SIGINT from TTY.